# Windows batch file - Loop through array of date range then split each item

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I would like to iterate through specific range of date from array.
Each item has start and end date delimited by space.
Below is my code but i cannot print correctly the split part. It only prints string1=

What do i missed? Thanks in advance.

```
SET dates[0]=01/01/2016 02/01/2016
SET dates[1]=03/01/2016 04/01/2016

set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined dates[%x%] (
    rem echo !dates[%x%]!
    set "str=!dates[%x%]!"

    echo !str!  

    set "string1=%str: =" & set "string2=%"

    echo string1=%string1%
    echo string1=%string2%

    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
```

Comment: Read the tag info before you add tags! I'm quite sure tags [tag:dos] and [tag:ms-dos] do not apply here (unless you are really working on this OS from the 1980s)!

Comment: @aschipfl granted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using delayed expansion (you have `setlocal enabledelayedexpanion` in your original code, I guess), but forgot the following two lines:

```
echo string1=%string1%
echo string1=%string2%
```

Correct them to:

```
echo string1=!string1!
echo string1=!string2!
```